# Standard Object Relation Child Name?

Tags: soql

I am trying to complete Apex Specialist Super badge and wondering why this query is successful:

```
SELECT Id, Equipment__c, Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
```

Why is this not working?

```
SELECT Id, Equipment__c, Product2__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
```

I'm completely lost, Where does `Equipment__r` come from?

Obviously, `Equipment` is originally `Product2` object. The pre-work wants us to change the tab/label to Equipment from Product2.

[image]

[image]

p.s I am not seeking for solution, just trying to understand SOQL/Object specification.

Answer (score 0):

When querying data via a lookup field, you need to specify the name of the lookup field and the field on the related object.

The field `Equipment__r` comes from the name of the lookup field on the Equipment Maintenance Item object. `Equipment__c` is the name of the lookup field and `Product2` is the name of the object it is looking up to.

There is no field called `Product2__c`, which is why your second query does not work.

Answer (score -1):

After I examined this, I may find an answer.
In conclusion, when you query a parent object (other than `Id` field and even it is Standard object) from child object, you need to put `__r` with your custom field API name with parent object field name.
Renaming tabs/labels has nothing do with this.

- Created a `Test__c` object with lookup field called `Account__c` with `Account` object.
- When I executed a query like this, it is successful.

```sql
SELECT Id, Account__c, Account__r.Name FROM Test__c
```

- After I changed field name `Account__c` to `Client__c`, the SOQL above threw an error:

```
Didn't understand relationship 'Account__r' in field path.... (omitted)
```

- This SOQL was successful:

```sql
SELECT Id, Client__c, Client__r.Name FROM Test__c
```